# AsyncTask not calling onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute

Tags: android

I am doing a android app which have a function to download the image while i clicked on the imageview. I have used Asynctask to start a new thread for downloading.However, the onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute method are never called. i have attached my codes.
The following is my code for main activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            String uri = "";
            if(!event.hasImage1())
            {
                uri = Configuration.SERVER_IP + "/" +event.getImgLink1();
                ImageDownloadTask task = new ImageDownloadTask(imageView1, StaffViewEventActivity.this);
                task.execute(uri);  
            }
        }
    });
```

Then this is my code for Asyntask class:

```
public class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

private static String TAG = "ImageDownloadTask";
private ImageView imageView;
private StaffViewEventActivity activity;

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground:" + params[0]);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);
    InputStream is = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        long length = httpEntity.getContentLength();
        Log.i(TAG, "start downloading image");
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
        if (is != null) {
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[128];
            int read = -1;
            int count = 0;
            while ((read = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buf, 0, read);
                count += read;
                publishProgress((int)(count * 1.0f / length));
            }

            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,  

                             data.length);
            Log.i(TAG, "finish downloading image");
            return bit;
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (baos != null) {
                baos.close();
            }
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public ImageDownloadTask(ImageView imageView, StaffViewEventActivity activity)
{
    this.imageView = imageView;
    this.activity =activity;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    Log.i("DownloadImgTask", "progress:" + progress[0]);
    //photoView.setProgress(progress[0]);                
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    activity.updateImageStatus(imageView.getId());
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    Log.i(TAG, "DownloadImgTask cancel...");
    super.onCancelled();
}


}
```

The doInBackground method is running and i can get the image through 
    task.execute(uri).get();
But i cannot get my onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute called. Can any1 help me with this problems, really appreciated.

Comment: Post the contents of your Logcat. Keep in mind that onPostExexute will not be called if doInBackground() could not be executed.

Comment: are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Make sure your while loop isn't stuck.

Comment: onPostExecute called when doInbackground function returns that is task completed in the function. Just check whether your doinbackground returns.

Comment: @VinaySShenoy, i think my doInBackground returns a bitmap. as i can get the bitmap through using task.execute.get();   The following is what i got in my logcat, i am running my app on android 2.3;                                     10-10 06:37:28.224: I/ImageDownloadTask(1917): start downloading image
10-10 06:43:47.204: I/ImageDownloadTask(1958): doInBackground:http://XXXX.com.au/XXXXX/1201210051352352.jpg
10-10 06:43:47.395: I/ImageDownloadTask(1958): start downloading image
10-10 06:43:47.714: I/ImageDownloadTask(1958): finish downloading ima

Comment: @Waqas , i dont have any exception in my logcat. I have testes the Bitmap downloaded from my server with 1. a if statement check and 2.task.execute.get(); Both result shows that the Bitmap is successfully downloaded. I have also tried using a onClick method from the XML file add ImageView with onClick="onDownloadClick", But none of those approaches can solve my problem...Got stucked for 1 day already, so sad

Comment: before `return null;` in **doInBackground**, can you log a message which confirms that your code hits the end for this method?

Comment: Hi@Waqas , Thx for ur response. unfortunately the doInBackground actually did not reach the end to execute "return null". I am thinking whether i should do my image downloading using other approach..

Comment: this might be because you have changed signature of doinbackground.. protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) you replaced object with bitmap.. can you keep original signature and try.. just try.. dont know  whether it is usefull or not.

Comment: @sachin Thx for you suggestions. But I have changed Bitmap to Object and it is still not working, . However, i found it working on Android 4.1, the onPostExecute and onProgressUpdate are called when running on 4.1 VM device.but it is still not working on Android2.2 and 2.3